Two back button presses always quit a PWA app on Android
I have a PWA application that is a SPA with internal navigation - there is a page stack and upon pressing the "back" button, the topmost page is removed to reveal the previous one.
It works perfectly using the in-app back button, but I cannot for the life of me get the Android hardware back button to work.
All the materials on here and elsewhere point to the solution of using history.pushState and then listening for the popstate event.
I have tried all the different possible solutions, but to no avail. The first back button press works as expected, but two presses in a row (regardless of time inbetween them, so not a "double-click") always quit the app regardless of what I pushState into the history. If I interact with app in any other way (even as just randomly tapping on an empty area), then one back press works again.
Any ideas anyone?

Without code we'd just be guessing.  Paste in how you're handling the back button (if you aren't, that's likely the issue).

I've tried countless different options. And I am handling the back button - like I described, pressing it once works. Pressing it once, just tapping on the screen - pressing it again - also works, both two back actions are handled properly. Just two consecutive back button presses trigger an app quit, even if they're 15 minutes apart.
But how it's done currently:
Every page load adds an entry to the history with:
window.history.pushState({}, '');
And then listen to the "popstate" event:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(evt){     App.Page.goBack('right'); });
